# How does node in mjs mode load cjs files?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I am trying to write a loader in node >= 14 but struggling with supporting cjs files.

Officially the loader docs say they don’t support loading cjs files… but then how does node load such files when in mjs mode?

I guess that one thing I could do is translate a cjs file into an mjs file as I find them. But I’d be happier doing that work if I knew that there was no way I could use code that is already in node.

Comment: What do you mean "write a loader"?  Even in an ESM module file in nodejs, you can use dynamic `import` to load CommonJS files or you can get access to `require()` with [`module.createRequire()`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename).

Comment: What I mean is a module loader. Module loaders don't currently support CommonJS but that must be possible I think because node can currently load CJS modules and make them accessible to MJS modules. I presume that what is happening there is some sort of translation. 

I think I found something [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2cc7a91a5d855b4ff78f21f1bb8d4e55131d0615/lib/internal/modules/esm/translators.js#L168) which suggests that ESM is doing translating when it loads a CJS file.

Guess I just need to implement that.

Comment: Why are you trying to write your  own loader?  What is the purpose?  Nodejs knows how to load both ESM and CommonJS files already - built in.

Comment: Because I don’t want to load them from disc.

Comment: Load from where then?  Network?  You might want to make the question focus on your actual problem because others may have solved this before and there may even be modules to use.

Comment: Sure. But this does describe my problem. Loaders are a thing, loading cjs via mjs is a thing. I am just trying to work out how to do both at the same time. It’s an esoteric part of node. But it’s there.

Comment: Well, you're going on 4 days here without any other responses so I don't think the bait is attracting any help so I was suggesting a different tact - up to you though.